# Редактор конфига в админке

Tags: php, config, control-panel

Добрый день.

Появилась необходимость написать админку для сайта. Очевидно, что большинство изменений будет происходить с конфигом сайта.
В связи с этим вопрос: целесообразно ли в качестве конфига иметь именно файл (аля config.php с массивом настроек, а не таблицу в БД). Если да, то есть-ли какой-то велосипед для вывода и записи в него изменённых данных сайта, или надо всё руками через регулярки делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А почему бы не использовать ini файл для хранения настроек?

---

`config.ini`

```
SITE_URL = http://example.com
ADMIN_EMAIL = admin@example.com
```

и парсим

```
$config = parse_ini_file('config.ini');

foreach($config as $conf_name => $conf_value)
{
    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$conf_name.'" value="'.$conf_value.'" />';
}
```

после сабмита формы - форичим `$_POST` собираем в кучу и записываем все в файл.

Как вариант, может будет интересен.

Comment: Действительно, достойный вариант. Спасибо. А функция последующей записи есть вот тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268378/create-ini-file-write-values-in-php